# TFS 2013 with git. How to get list of associated tasks between builds?

Tags: git, tfs, continuous-integration

I have feature based branching model. Development is performed in feature branch. When is feature done, branch is merged back to main. Every commit have associated task.

Is there way to get list of task which was associated with all commits between build x and build y?

I found a lot of questions about it, but they was a bit outdated.

Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do a build TFS automatically updates the "Integrated In" field on any associated tasks with the build name. You should easily be able to create what you are looking for through querying work it's tracking.